# Rendering output to arbitary quadrilateral

Tags: directx, windows, .net

I want to render output on a device to an arbitary quadirlateral, i.e. project texture on to a quad. What are the possible ways I could implement it?

Till now, I have investigated:

- Drawing textured quadrilateral - Quads look odd as they are composed of triangles, and the distortion looks odd. The issue I'm facing has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939119/directx-vertex-rendering-unable-to-get-texture-to-display-correctly-for-trapetz) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748900/problems-with-texture-deformation-in-opengl-es-1-1-on-quad-made-out-of-triangle/4764384#4764384) as well.
- Setting transformation on device - Need help in getting this implemented.
- Pixel shaders - Not able to implement the desired effect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try searching for Render to texture. I got enough results.. e.g. http://www.two-kings.de/tutorials/dxgraphics/dxgraphics16.html
Once you get your texture, just map it to a quad.. I don't see why this wouldn't work, since it's how many engines do it (e.g. Ogre3D has this technique out of the box and it is working for a plethora of effects..)

Comment: Well, I did try setting the texture and drawing a quad, but the overall distortion looked like the quad is composed of two triangles and each triangle distorted independently.

Comment: You may want to review a basic "texture a quad" tutorial before continuing, pay attention to the camera/projection matrix setup and how the quad itself is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't if it will help you or not but if you want to implement it with pixel shader see if the shader below can help you.

```
/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0,0/minValue>
/// <maxValue>1,1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0,0</defaultValue>
float2 LeftTop :register(C0);
/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0,0/minValue>
/// <maxValue>1,1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0,1</defaultValue>
float2 LeftBottom :register(C1);
/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0,0/minValue>
/// <maxValue>1,1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1,0</defaultValue>
float2 RightTop :register(C2);
/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0,0/minValue>
/// <maxValue>1,1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>1,1</defaultValue>
float2 RightBottom    :register(C3);

sampler input : register(s0);

float3x3 Adjoint(float3x3 m)
{
    float3x3 adj;

    // Calculate the adjoint matrix
    adj._11 = m._22*m._33 - m._23*m._32;
    adj._12 = m._13*m._32 - m._12*m._33;
    adj._13 = m._12*m._23 - m._13*m._22;

    adj._21 = m._23*m._31 - m._21*m._33;
    adj._22 = m._11*m._33 - m._13*m._31;
    adj._23 = m._13*m._21 - m._11*m._23;

    adj._31 = m._21*m._32 - m._22*m._31;
    adj._32 = m._12*m._31 - m._11*m._32;
    adj._33 = m._11*m._22 - m._12*m._21;

    return adj;
}





float4 Projection(float2 uv)
{
    float a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;

    //setting variable names as variable names in algorithem
   float x0,x1,x2,x3,y0,y1,y2,y3;
   x0=LeftTop.x;
   y0=LeftTop.y;
   x1=RightTop.x;
   y1=RightTop.y;
   x2=RightBottom.x;
   y2=RightBottom.y;
   x3=LeftBottom.x;
   y3=LeftBottom.y;

   //If the polygon is Parallegoram
    a=x1-x0;
    b=x2-x1;
    c=x0;
    d=y1-y0;
    e=y2-y1;
    f=y0;
    g=0;
    h=0;


    float x3minusx0 = x3-x0;
    float SigmaX=(b - x3minusx0);
    float y3minusy0 = y3- y0;
    float SigmaY=( e - y3minusy0);

    //If the polygon is not a Parallegoram the following changes need to be done to the variables
    //if( SigmaX!=0 || SigmaY!=0)
    {    
        float DeltaX1=-b;
        float DeltaX2=x3-x2;
        float DeltaY1=-e;
        float DeltaY2=y3-y2;
        float2x2 mat1 = {DeltaX1,DeltaX2,DeltaY1,DeltaY2};
        float denom = determinant(mat1);
        float2x2 mat2 = {SigmaX,DeltaX2,SigmaY,DeltaY2};
        g= determinant(mat2) / denom;
        float2x2 mat3= {DeltaX1,SigmaX,DeltaY1,SigmaY};
        h= determinant(mat3) /denom;
        a+=g*x1;
        b=(x3minusx0)+h*x3;
        d+=g*y1;
        e=y3minusy0+h*y3;
    }

    float3x3 ProjectionMatrix3x3= {a,d,g,b,e,h,c,f,1};
    float3x3 AdjoitOfProjectionMatrix3x3= Adjoint(ProjectionMatrix3x3);

    float3 inputVector=float3(uv.x,uv.y,1);
    float3 outputVector= mul(inputVector,AdjoitOfProjectionMatrix3x3);

   float2 FoundPoint;   

   //Converting homogenious point to noramal 2D cordinate
   FoundPoint.x=outputVector.x/outputVector.z;
   FoundPoint.y=outputVector.y/outputVector.z;

   //some point grater than 1   
   if(FoundPoint.x <0 || FoundPoint.y<0 || FoundPoint.x > 1 || FoundPoint.y > 1 ) 
   {
        return float4(0,0,0,0);
   }
   else
   {
        return tex2D(input, FoundPoint);
   }
}


float4 main(float2 uv: TEXCOORD) : COlOR
{
  return Projection(uv);
}


technique TransformTexture {
  pass P0     {        
    PixelShader  = compile ps_2_0 main(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to map a square/rectangular texture to an arbitrary quad is projective interpolation.  I've written [an article](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/05/26/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/) showing how to do this.

The short version: you interpolate UVs across the quad in a way analogous to how GPUs do it for perspective-correct rendering (which, as you may have noticed, does *not* produce a visible seam between the two triangles).  To do this, you need to calculate a false "depth" value for each vertex of the quad, and do the interpolation using homogeneous coordinates based on this "depth".  Full details are in the article linked above.